# Force off screen WebView to draw

Tags: android, webview, scroll, drawing, off-screen

I have a slider of WebViews where each WebView perfectly fit the screen size.
The user can scroll left to right and vise versa.

Problem comes when a WebView never shown before comes in the visible area. Its content is preloaded but the whole surface is blank for several milliseconds until Android understands it became visible and shows its content.

Because a picture is worth a thousand words :
[image: Schema]

I do a "requestLayout" each time a view is added. I've tried to invalidate them and even 
to do a fake scroll... but with no success.

The target API level is 17.

Comment: Hey, Did you find the solution? Thanks